# Mercurial - listing a user's heads

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way to list heads that were created by a specific user?

With the `hg heads` command I am unable to filter on user.

While with `hg log` I can filter on a user, but am unable to figure out how to list only the last changeset on a branch.

**UPDATE**:

Thanks to Tim Henigan's answer below. I arrived at the following conclusion.

```
log -r "head() and not closed() and user('<username>')"
```

In my particular case I wanted only the latest heads in reverse order so I made an alias for this functionality.

```
[alias]
myhist = log -r "reverse(head() and not closed() and user('<username>'))" --template "{rev}: {branches}\n" -l 10
```

so that calling `hg myhist` gives me up to ten recent changesets which are all the last one on their branch. I am using the `--template` option to only see the revision number and branch name so as to get a quick overview of my recent activity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using a newer version of Mercurial, you can build this query using [revsets](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets):

`hg log -r "heads(all()) and not closed() and user('<user>')"`

Comment: Thanks, that's awesome but not exactly what I was looking for. I think a better wording for my question would be: "give me the last changeset I have created on all branches". Your answer led me to the solution for me though. I'll update my question with this.

Answer (score 0):

The above suggestion got me close but didn't quite work. this one worked better

```
hg log -u smoosvi -r "head() and not closed()"
```